# Generate local IP address at compile time in Java/Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an Android project that has configurations for multiple different servers. In the code, there is a switch statement that determines the server being used by the app depending on the value of a variable in the config. It looks something like this:

```
switch (TARGET_DOMAIN) {
    case PRODUCTION:
        api = "http://app.api.{omitted domain}.com/api/";
        break;
    case STAGING:
        api = "http://staging.{omitted domain}.com/api/";
        break;
    case LOCAL:
        api = "http://192.168.1.4:8000/api/";
        break;
    case EMULATOR:
        api = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/";
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("TARGET_DOMAIN is unset");
}
```

I am interested in knowing if there is some way I can programatically replace the IP under LOCAL with the local IP during compilation (the local IP of the machine doing the compiling). I am using Eclipse, if that makes a difference. Would this be possible or am I just a crazy person?

Bonus points if you know I way I could eliminate the EMULATOR case and just have the IP intelligently determined as 10.0.2.2 if the app is being run on an Android emulator.

Comment: This is very possible once you start using Gradle for Android and custom build types, either directly as your build engine or by using Android Studio for your builds. From Ant or Eclipse, this would be annoying to set up.

Comment: Why not just localhost or <name>.local?

Comment: <name>.local presents the same problem as manually writing in the IP (plus the machine might not have a registered name in the network) and localhost does not work because the code is actually running on an Android device, not the machine it was compiled on (where the server is running).